# Empty column in grid, selecteditem null in RowCommand

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu, selecteditem

I have a datagrid and some of the columns are shown as blank, null value from code behind. On right click over column, we are performing operations by getting the selectedrow. In case, we have null value in column, and right click, the row is blank in rowcommand.

Any idea, how to still get row when selecteditem is null?

XAML :

```
 <DataGrid>
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu>
               <MenuItem Header="Edit" ToolTip="Edit the inputs."                             
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.MenuEditRowCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"                             
                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}">

               </MenuItem>
         </ContextMenu>
     </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModel :

```
public ICommand MenuEditRowCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_menuEditRowCommand == null)
        {
            _menuEditRowCommand = new ExceptionHandlingDelegateCommand<Class_NAme>(MenuEditRowMethod);
        }
        return _menuEditRowCommand;
    }
}

private void MenuEditRowMethod(Class_NAme Inputs)
{
    if (Inputs != null)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `ContextMenu` for the `DataGridRow` container and bind to its `DataContext`:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.MenuEditRowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" ToolTip="Edit the inputs."                             
                                          Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"                             
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}">
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```